# Assignment Problem: Workers assigned Tasks each Day in a Week. Priorize similar tasks across days

Tags: variable-assignment, simplex, hungarian-algorithm, assignment-problem

Set of Workers `W` assigned to Tasks `T`. Workers can only work 1 task on a given day, and only 1 task can be worked by a worker on a given day. Cost to work a given task is equal for all workers and tasks.

However I would like to take into account different behaviors such as location or task type.

- On Day One:

  - Worker `W1` assigned to Task `T1` with type `Y1` at Location `L1`
  - Worker `W2` assigned to Task `T2` with type `Y2` at Location `L1`
- On Day Two:

  The assignment of `W1` would be be incentivized to
  tasks with type `Y1` and location `L1`. Similarly I would like the
  assignment of `W1` to be incentivized to choose tasks with type `Y2`
  and location `L1`.

I have a brute force approach that arbitrarily starts with one Worker-Task combination, assigns them, and recalculates the incentive weights, until every worker is assigned. This approach considers all days at the same time, but does not seem optimal.